# Ninject instantiates singleton twice

Tags: c#, wpf, ninject

I initialize Ninject with following binding in a `NinjectModule`:

```
  Bind<MainWindow>()
    .ToSelf()
    .InSingletonScope();
```

Then when I query the `MainWindow` from kernel I get a different instance after the first call but the same instance on subsequent calls.

```
  var win1 = Container.Get<MainWindow>();
  var win2 = Container.Get<MainWindow>();
  var win3 = Container.Get<MainWindow>();
  Log.Debug("is it same? => " + (win1 == win2)+" "+(win2 == win3));
```

Result:

```
is it same? => False True
```

Why is that??

I have some dependencies to `MainWindow` inside the bindings too (if that plays a role):

```
  Bind<IDialogService>()
    .To<DialogService>()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("parent", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<MainWindow>());
```

Also: `MainWindow` has a property where it gets `DialogService` injected.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that one of the following two causes are to blame:

### Binding is done after first `Get<T>`

Since ninject does not separate container configuration from container usage with `Get<T>` etc, it's possible that

```
Bind<MainWindow>()
  .ToSelf()
  .InSingletonScope();
```

is performed only after the first `Get<MainWindow>` *or* (maybe) that it is performed twice, effectively replacing the binding and having the same effect - there'll be two singletons.

### Two Bindings

There's two separate bindings in place, like one with `IMainWindow` and one with `MainWindow`.

### Debugging

You might want to try to add an `OnActivation` to the binding and see how many times that's called. If it's not called for an instance, then the instance has been created by another binding.
For example:

```
Bind<MainWindow>()
  .ToSelf()
  .InSingletonScope()
  .OnActivation(x => Console.WriteLine("Instanciated a {0}", x));
```

Comment: Yes I added OnActivation before and it has shown that the `MainWindow` constructor was called two times. I could not make much sense out of the stacktraces yet. The problem seems to relate to my circular dependency problem between `DialogService` and `MainWindow` which I solved with property injection of `DialogService`. I used `Lazy<IDialogService>` as constructor parameter in `MainWindow`and this solved the problem for now.